# My gallery shows nothing

Tags: gallery, media-scanner

I've searched high and low and cannot find a solution to this problem. The other day I wiped my phone for various reasons. Ever since I did the wipe the gallery does not display any of the images that are already stored on the device. If I take a new picture it will go right into the /sdcard/DCIM/Camera directory and it will display in the gallery. Same thing happens if I download a picture it will go into /sdcard/Download and will display in the gallery.

However, any of the images that are already in any of the folders on my sdcard do not show up in the gallery. Is there a way to force the gallery to scan the sdcard or something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [media-scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) is usually triggered at each boot for the entire device, or whenever a medium is mounted for that medium. So you could try to either reboot (which you probably already did), or go to *Settings › Storage* and first remove and then "mount" the sd card again. Please let us know if that helped; if not, we might have further ideas. Good luck!